# In how many ways can a soccer team with $16$ players be placed in four cars if the owners drive their own cars?

Tags: combinatorics

A soccer team is taking $16$ players to a match in four cars. The owners of the cars drive their own cars and each take three other players as passengers. In how many ways can this be done?

Comment: Please I need it urgently

Comment: Hint: Think of the arrangement as breaking the 12 non-drivers into 4 distinguishable groups of 3 each.  The number of ways this can be done is a multinomial coefficient.

Answer (score 3):

The car owners have names A, B, C, D. First A picks three players from the $12$, then B picks three players from the remaining $9$, then C picks three players from the remaining $6$, and finally D accommodates the last three players. The numbers of choices for each of  B, C, D are independent of the choices the predecessors have made.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear where the car's owners will sit, so all we have to care about is where we put the other people.

There are $16 - 4 = 12$ places left in the cars, so there are $12!$ possibilities.

Comment: This would only be correct if it mattered who was sitting in each individual seat in each car.

Comment: I assumed this was the case. Otherwise, the answer uses combinations: this is: $\binom{12}{3} * \binom{9}{3} * \binom{6}{3}$

Comment: why would we multiply (12C3)∗(9C3)∗(6C3) together? why not add?